# lararave intervention image upload slow code review

Tags: laravel, file-upload, image-uploading, intervention

I have Upload File Controller method and it is slow on live server, I don't know why? Can you review if my code is structured okay? Is it in the right order? How to optimize my code pls?

```
    $id = Auth::user()->id;
    $image=$request->file('file');
    $fileName=time().uniqid(rand()).'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();

    //Resize image here    
    $background = Image::canvas(500, 500);  
    $background->fill('#fff');  

    $lphoto = Image::make($image->getRealpath());
    $lphoto->orientate();
    $lphoto->resize(500, 500, function ($constraint) {
        $constraint->upsize();
        $constraint->aspectRatio();
    });
    $lphoto->encode();

    $sphoto = Image::make($image->getRealpath());
    $sphoto->orientate();
    $sphoto->fit(186,180);
    $sphoto->encode(null, 90);

    $background->insert($lphoto, 'center');
    $background->encode();

    Storage::disk('public')->put( 'images/'.$year.'/'.$month."/".$day."/".$id."/".$fileName, $background);
    Storage::disk('public')->put( 'images/'.$year.'/'.$month."/".$day."/".$id.'/small-'.$fileName, $sphoto);
```

Comment: what specifically is slow? Because it might be the actual uploading of the image which is slow, and not the processing of the image. I think the browser will tell you if the file is still being uploaded.

Comment: I am using dropzone on the front with ajax to post file resize and save it. Everything work really fast but only uploading is very slow that is why I thought that my code can be better but I do not know how?

Comment: your code has nothing to do with the upload speed I believe. your issue probably lies on your server bandwidth/speed and internet connection